# PayPal setup with multiple receivers

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to make paypal payments available on my site where different people can sell their stuff. I know a lot of websites let you specify what your paypal address is and you get paid. I have paypal pro set up, but the receiver info in paypal payments pro is API username, API password and API signature. How can I change this to just use an email address for the receiver so I don't have to ask for all users' API info?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work with Website Payments Pro. You'll need PayPal Express Checkout or PayPal Adaptive Payments which allows for split or split & chained payments, respectively.
See also my answer in [Online payments for a middleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519936/online-payments-for-a-middleman/7520053#7520053)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of direct sending the money from A to B on your site without having a signature of B and without any kind of interaction with B. And there are business reasons for why it is impossible.

If asking the receivers signature is not an option to you, you can transfer the money as A->C->B, where C is your account (that is, making users to send money to you, and then sending the received money to the needed receivers).

Comment: Thanks for that. But how do the ticketing sites do it? For example, eventbrite, asks event organizers to put their paypal email addresses and proceeds from ticket sales go straight to the event organizer. They never ask for event organizer's API details, just their email address.

Comment: I never used such sites, but possibly they act as an intermediate (in my "A->C->B" scheme). That is, user is sending money to a ticketing company account (either by paypal or by any other means); and then ticketing company sends some money (minus their fee) to the event organizer by paypal.

Comment: +user1122025; that's what my answer addresses. Using Adaptive Payments you can set the organizer as a primary receiver by only specifying their email address. Optionally allowing you, as the secondary receiver, to receive a cut from the profit.