# Paypal API direct: buyer to seller payment(s)

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to be the middle man for a Paypal transaction without having anything thing to do with the transaction (PayPal account wise)

so the buyer pays directly into the seller's account and my site verify's the purchase (somehow) and emails download link.

How is this done and yes this is a coding question since it involves PayPal API and possible PHP workaround.

Any help would be happily received.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use [Paypal adaptive payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) to achieve this. Note that you need a PayPal Business account. A related question with answer:  [Online payments for a middleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519936/online-payments-for-a-middleman/7520053#7520053)

Comment: Thanks for that didn't word the question well enough to see other related questions!